# Replace MultiIndex's contents with DataFrame columns

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex, like so

```
In [88]: topic_word
Out[88]: 

                          n         p
topic_id token                       
0        functions        1  0.076923
         layer            7  0.538462
         layered          1  0.076923
         module           1  0.076923
         multi            1  0.076923
         perceptron       1  0.076923
         separable        1  0.076923
1        copy             1  0.200000
         electromyograph  1  0.200000
         physical         2  0.400000
         techniques       1  0.200000
2        aw               1  0.125000
         computed         1  0.125000
         region           3  0.375000
         regions          3  0.375000
3        autonomous       1  0.041667
         diverse          1  0.041667
         heterogeneity    1  0.041667
         heterogeneous    4  0.166667
         integrate        2  0.083333
```

How can I insert the contents of the MultiIndex back into regular columns, such that I can select them like any other column?

```
    topic_id token            n         p
0   0        functions        1  0.076923
1   0        layer            7  0.538462
2   0        layered          1  0.076923
3   0        module           1  0.076923
4   0        multi            1  0.076923
5   0        perceptron       1  0.076923
6   0        separable        1  0.076923
7   1        copy             1  0.200000
8   1        electromyograph  1  0.200000
9   1        physical         2  0.400000
10  1        techniques       1  0.200000
11  2        aw               1  0.125000
12  2        computed         1  0.125000
13  2        region           3  0.375000
14  2        regions          3  0.375000
15  3        autonomous       1  0.041667
16  3        diverse          1  0.041667
17  3        heterogeneity    1  0.041667
18  3        heterogeneous    4  0.166667
19  3        integrate        2  0.083333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing an ordinary [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#remove-reset-the-index-reset-index) puts these columns back as columns:

```
df.reset_index()
```

> For `DataFrame` with multi-level index, return new DataFrame with labeling information in the columns under the index names...

*Note: [the `drop` argument](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) argument (if set `True`) will **not** add  the index columns:*

> `drop` : boolean, **default False**
>       Do not try to insert index into dataframe columns.
>       This resets the index to the default integer index.

Comment: Fantastic.  As an aside, is there a reverse operation -- turning a column into an index?

Comment: @duckworthd :) That would be [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) (Note: you can set `append=True`).

Comment: Splendid!  Just what I was looking for.  A lot of operations I know in pandas rely on column names, and I never knew how to go back and forth between columns and indices.